# How to retrieve FormData in Laravel

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5

I am sending formdata from Angular 2 to Laravel API to save the  recorded voice from RecordRTC js. Checked the filename, filetype and blob file on console. it is showing. but not able to retrieve on Laravel backend code.

```
 public uploadToServer() {
    let blob  = this.recordRTC instanceof Blob ? this.recordRTC : this.recordRTC.blob;
    let fileType = blob.type.split('/')[0] || 'audio';
    let fileName = (Math.random() * 1000).toString().replace('.', '');
    if (fileType === 'audio') {
      fileName += '.' + (!!navigator.mozGetUserMedia ? 'ogg' : 'wav');
    } else {
      fileName += '.webm';
    }
    // create FormData
    var formData: FormData = new FormData();
    console.log(fileName);
    console.log(blob);
    console.log(fileType);
    formData.append(fileType + '-filename', fileName);
    formData.append(fileType + '-blob', blob);
    console.log(formData);
    this.recordingService.saveRecording(formData).subscribe(
      data => this.saveRecordingSuccess(data),
      error => this.saveRecordingFail(error)
    );
  }
```

Laravel Code:-

```
 public function saveRecording(Request $request)
  {
    $fileName = '';
    $tempName = '';
    $file_idx = '';

    if (!empty($_FILES['audio-blob'])) {
        $file_idx = 'audio-blob';
        $fileName = $_POST['audio-filename'];
        $tempName = $_FILES[$file_idx]['tmp_name'];
    }
    if (empty($fileName) || empty($tempName)) {
        if(empty($tempName)) {
            echo 'Invalid temp_name: '.$tempName;
            return;
        }
        echo 'Invalid file name: '.$fileName;
        return;
    }
    $filePath = public_path('voiceRecording/' . $fileName);

    // make sure that one can upload only allowed audio/video files
    $allowed = array(
        'webm',
        'wav'
    );
    $extension = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (!$extension || empty($extension) || !in_array($extension, $allowed)) {
        echo 'Invalid file extension: '.$extension;
        return;
    }
    if (!move_uploaded_file($tempName, $filePath)) {
      // error code
        return;
    }
}
```

In laravel code I have not receiving any files and post data.

Comment: You might want to check some doc, this is not a correct way to send a file with `FormData`.

Comment: Edited my question please check it once.

Comment: You don't use `$_FILES` in Laravel. You should be using `$request->file('audio-blob')`. As @thefallen suggests, you should read up on File uploads using Laravel.
What do you get if you do `dd($request->files())` in your `saveRecording` function?

Comment: It is showing empty.

Comment: Fixed the issue. 
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var data = {};
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.recordRTC.getBlob());
    reader.onload = function () {
        data = {
          value: reader.result.split(',')[1],
          filename: fileName,
          fileType: fileType
        };
      console.log(reader.result.split(',')[1]);
    };

Answer (score -1):

You have to put on your form the mime type, like in JQuery Ajax, have the property

```
mimeType: "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: this does not help, formdata from browset not helping

Comment: Shreyan if you have the same problem as Maneesh, he found a solution, and he put in his comments, maybe it helps you.

Comment: his issue was in front , i am getting in back empty at laravel controller

Comment: The reason for the empty response may be any validation, middleware or anything before, try to debug the data flow from your post to the backend. Make simple post only with text and increase the data.

Comment: Though that also did not helped, But I managed to get things with form data on api, for which i was struggling for a week, would post answer soon